# Sync Azure Analysis Server model in Azure using Sync-AzAnalysisServicesInstance

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-analysis-services, hybrid-runbook-worker

We are using  Hybrid worker groups and we have a Group Name that is pointing to one of our Remote Server,
Now I want to Sync my Azure analysis server model using the powershell script, Is anyone having the powershell script to connect and 
sync my model?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Once a Hybrid Worker is configured, create a Webhook as described in the section [Consume with Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-refresh-azure-automation#consume-with-data-factory). The only difference here is to select the **Run on > Hybrid Worker** option when configuring the Webhook.

Example webhook using Hybrid Worker:

[image]

The following code snippet is an example of how to perform the Azure Analysis Services model refresh using a PowerShell Runbook.

```
param
(
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $false)]
    [object] $WebhookData,

    [Parameter (Mandatory = $false)]
    [String] $DatabaseName,
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $false)]
    [String] $AnalysisServer,
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $false)]
    [String] $RefreshType
)

$_Credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "ServicePrincipal"

# If runbook was called from Webhook, WebhookData will not be null.
if ($WebhookData)
{ 
    # Retrieve AAS details from Webhook request body
    $atmParameters = (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $WebhookData.RequestBody)
    Write-Output "CredentialName: $($atmParameters.CredentialName)"
    Write-Output "AnalysisServicesDatabaseName: $($atmParameters.AnalysisServicesDatabaseName)"
    Write-Output "AnalysisServicesServer: $($atmParameters.AnalysisServicesServer)"
    Write-Output "DatabaseRefreshType: $($atmParameters.DatabaseRefreshType)"

    $_databaseName = $atmParameters.AnalysisServicesDatabaseName
    $_analysisServer = $atmParameters.AnalysisServicesServer
    $_refreshType = $atmParameters.DatabaseRefreshType

    Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -DatabaseName $_databaseName -RefreshType $_refreshType -Server $_analysisServer -ServicePrincipal -Credential $_credential
}
else 
{
    Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -RefreshType $RefreshType -Server $AnalysisServer -ServicePrincipal -Credential $_Credential
}
```

For more details, refer "[Use a Hybrid worker with Azure Analysis Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-refresh-azure-automation#use-a-hybrid-worker-with-azure-analysis-services)".

Hope this helps.